# Serverless SNS filterPolicy does not put filter in place when subscription created

Tags: amazon-sns, serverless, aws-serverless

I'm using the following function definition:

```
missing:
    handler: functions/eeegMissing.handler
    events:
      - sns: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxx
        filterPolicy:
              type:
                - EPILOG_PAGE_DATA_RECEIVED
```

The SNS topic already exists. When I deploy it, a subscription is created with the name

```
arn:aws:lambda:us-west-2:xxx:function:eeeg-dev-missing`
```

but the filter is blank. I would expect the filter to show as:

```
{ "type":["EPILOG_PAGE_DATA_RECEIVED"]}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: I removed your unnecessary code quotes. Please inform yourself [how to use _code sections_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in your questions and answers.

Comment: @zx485 thanks, I tried to update it but at the time I didn't see the edit option... I'll do better :D

Comment: I'm glad that you saw some sense in my comment. Understanding this will give you a bright future on SO.

Answer (score 3):

You just have a minor syntax error. I have a Serverless function with the following event and it works:

```
events:
- sns: 
    arn: ${self:custom.devicesTopicArn}
    filterPolicy:
      operation:
      - INSERT
```

So in your case, it should be:

```
missing:
  handler: functions/eeegMissing.handler
  events:
    - sns:
        arn: arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:xxx
        filterPolicy:
          type:
            - EPILOG_PAGE_DATA_RECEIVED
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify the previous answer, per [the Serverless docs](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/sns#using-a-pre-existing-topic), when specifying a topic by arn (versus name), the arn value must include the `arn:` keyword (in addition to the `arn:` prefix included in the AWS resource name).